# Appropriate way to access environment variables in google cloud run (docker) with rust

Tags: docker, rust, macros, google-cloud-run

I built an API in rust and am deploying it via Google Cloud Run. Within my API I access a URI for a remote database stored as an environment variable.

When I run the program on my local computer the environment variable can be accessed using `env!("MONGODB_URI_2")`.

When I deploy the program to gcloud with the flag `--set-env-vars "MONGODB_URI_2", "theurigoeshere"` the same env macro can't find the variable and panics.

**Edit:**
I tried removing the underscores from the key and making the text all lowercase before posting this, it didn't help..

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Good link @cafce25, ammended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like [`--set-env-vars`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy#--set-env-vars) expects `=` as the separator between key and value, while `,` separates multiple variables:

```
gcloud run deploy --set-env-vars MONGODB_URI_2=theurigoeshere
```

Also note that the [`env!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.env.html) macro gives you compile-time environment variables, so if you want runtime environment variables, use [`std::env::var`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.var.html). It looks like compile-time environment variables will work here, but it's a common mistake so it's important to keep in mind.